# Function to receive sheet id as parameter and return the spreadsheet object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to define a function in google apps script that receives the sheet id as input and returns the spreadsheet object so I can do further stuff with it like get range and values.

```
function spreadsheetCall() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1eZcZ0e1AQZ4DRLO9HQsF024qsmraIewY6LUkWYicYmY").getSheetByName("Semanal");
    return ss
};

Logger.log(spreadsheetCallString().getRange("A1").getValues());
```

When I try that it works like a charm, I can get the range and values I want, but the function is not dynamic since the sheet id is hardcoded into the function. I am trying to have something like this

```
function spreadsheetCall(sheetID) {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID).getSheetByName("Semanal");
    return ss
};
```

where if I have a list of multiple sheets I do not have to make a function for each but rather apply the same one multiple times if needed to get what I want. any guidance is helpful, I know basic python so maybe javascript works different idk, just asking to see if it is possible to do what I am thinking of I should find another approach.
Thanks

Tried creating a string with the spreadsheet call and then taking away the quotation marks to return it in a function and then use another function to try and make the proper call but did not work.

Comment: You actually should take a look at the sheets API it may be just what you want and many user believe it to be much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
function getallsheetsatonce(sheetId="11yNxdh_GIokeHIctdzt3LDKVm7rYIJvAPlMLzunn7zE") {
  let obj = {sA:[]}
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
    obj.sA.push(sh.getName());
    obj[sh.getName()]= sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  });
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, did not fully use your code but rather took the idea of passing the name of the argument of the function and the value when defining it and then tried using the function I created and passing different arguments and it works like I want it to

function spreadsheetCall(sheetId="1eZcZ0e1AQZ4DRLO9HQsF024qsmraIewY6LUkWYicYmY") {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId)
    return sheet;
};

defined it that way and then when I use spreadsheetCall() and pass any other sheet ID as argument it works great.